# Data Scraping a Table with Multiple pages

Tags: r, purrr, rvest

I am currently trying to retrieve a table from the CDC website however (https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/prevalence-maps.html#states) the table in question has multiple pages that must be scrolled through and I am having difficulty retrieving it and putting it into RStudio. I have tried to utilize the possibly() function from purrr but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

link <- "https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/prevalence-maps.html"
xpaths <- paste0('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0', 1:9, '"]/table[2]')

scrape_table <- function(link, xpath){

  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = xpath) %>%
    html_table() %>%
    flatten_df %>%
    setNames(c("State", "Prevalence", "95 CI"))

}

scrape_table_possibly <- possibly(scrape_table, otherwise = NULL)

scraped_tables <- map(xpaths, ~ scrape_table_possibly(link = link, xpath = .x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The page source doesn't contain the data but gets external data by JS so you can't scrape it by `rvest` anyway. The table you want is from this file: https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/maps/2019-overall.csv

Edit: I scrolled down and saw other tables:

https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/maps/2019-white.csv
https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/maps/2019-hispanic.csv
https://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/maps/2019-black.csv